# Odd Map bug on Jquery Mobile

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile

i get a weird behavior of my google map in jQuerymobile, the problem is that when maps loads its not expanding itself all over the canvas..
instead of keep trying explain :

http://jsfiddle.net/yonarbel/x5nbtpgo/4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // When map page opens get location and display map
        $('#map-page').live('pagecreate', function() {
            initializeMap(42, -73);
        });

        function initializeMap(lat, lng) {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="header">
             <h1>Home Page</h1>

        </div>
        <div data-role="content"> <a href="#map-page">go to Map page</a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="map-page">
        <div data-role="header">
             <h1>Map Page</h1>

        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 400px"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `pagecreate` does not suffice..

You should fire a `resize` event on the map (*which makes it recalculate sizes*) on `pageshow` event

```
        (function(){
            var map;

            // When map page opens get location and display map
            $('#map-page').live('pageshow', function() {
                initializeMap(42, -73);
            });
            $('#map-page').live('pageshow',function(){
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
            });
            function initializeMap(lat, lng) {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            }
        }());
```

(*inserted all code in a IIFE to avoid polluting the global scope with the `map` variable*)

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/x5nbtpgo/6/

Comment: Thanks! 
i switched the "live" to be  :
$(document).on('pageshow', '#map-page', function () {

Comment: good idea to restrict to the spacific page. I was going by your demo code and just tried to solve the issue.